# AppleScript. How can I delete a hidden folder or move it to the trash?

Tags: macos, applescript

I tried to do this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    move folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Mark:Desktop:.folder" to the trash
end tell
```

But Script Editor talks about an error like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    move folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Mark:Desktop:.folder" to trash
        --> error number -1728 from folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Mark:Desktop:.folder"
```

P.S. And I'm sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete the folder, you won't find it in your trash...

```
tell application "System Events"
    delete folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Mark:Desktop:.folder"
end tell
```